# Estimating the number of nodes of a discretization scheme

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Working on a problem in partial differential equations, I have come across a function 
$$f\colon [0, T]\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$$
which is continuous and non-decreasing, and whose maximum is $M=f(T)$. I need to have a control over its growth, so I discretized the time interval: 
$$[0, T]=[0, \tau_1)\cup [\tau_1, \tau_2)\cup\ldots\cup [\tau_{K-1}, T],$$
where the nodes $\{\tau_k\ :\ k=0\ldots K\}$ are chosen in such a way that 
$$f(\tau_{k+1})-f(\tau_k)\le \frac{1}{C}$$
for a fixed constant $C$.

> **Question**. Can we give an upper bound over $K$, the number of nodes?

Specifically, I hope that $K$ can be bounded above by some quantity which depends only on $C$ and $M$ and *not* on $f$ and/or $T$. Is this true?

Comment: Is it a lower bound that you want?

Comment: @Tomás:  No, sorry, I am interested in an upper bound. The least nodes, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty clear that the nodes can be chosen in such a way that $K\leq MC$. This is sharp, for instance, for linear functions.